# Force all rest arguments to be optional in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to make all rest arguments optional?

```js
function thisIsAfunction<TArgs extends unknown[] = []>(callback: (firstParam: string, ...args: TArgs) => void) { 
    /* Do something */ 
}

// This is okay ✅
thisIsAfunction((type: string, name?: string, id?: number) => {});

// This should cause a type error ❌
// (is it possible to force all args to be optional?)
thisIsAfunction((type: string, name: string, id: number) => {});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFjAzgSXQQVJWBAHgBUcAnAc3UQFMAPKWsAExvAGsw4B3MAbQC6iALyIhAPgAUEAIYAbeQCNZEDgC5EU4DHLooABVnlZAW037yMMJQA0iAHRPj1TWSroAlKImIAbnAwLN4A3ogAUIhRiAD0AFSIACJwiOhwprSo1pSIcTERAL7h4TH5JGg0GIhwHLIAnoiAoOThWVi4+NDwYFJSUHUADrQWUFY29mBmtAD8w6N2iEEziGAgpkq05N4iviEFngDcxaWI5VXoKHAg8iyIciDotIiyyAOPG+Rw5IiAMuQl+VJVGBQRD9ODodAwJTyR5QFLAT4QR4KeRPDzIFLrar9QgTeRTTwtCrYPDgToIHp9QazbLjSbUsYLFiaFZrDZbHZ7fZAA)

Here is the extended example:

```js
type SelectCommand<TArgs extends unknown[]> = (filter: any, ...args: TArgs) => void;
class DataSource<TSelectArgs extends unknown[] = []> {
    select: SelectCommand<TSelectArgs>;
    constructor(config: {select: SelectCommand<TSelectArgs>}) {
        this.select = config.select;
    }
}

const ds = new DataSource({
    // This should cause a type error for id and type because they are not optional
    // Is it possible to force the rest arguments to be optional?
    select: (filter: any, id: number, type: string) => { /* Do something */ }
})

ds.select('Search', 1, 'type'); // This should work
ds.select('Search'); // And this should always work
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2EDGwDCB7AtpghgOwBMAeAFQEEAnAcwGcoIAPYCQugVzwGs90B3PANoBdAHxQAvFAAUAMwCW8ZhQBcUfCAA0UAHS6c1GqvIGAlBLEA3dHIIBuAFBJ4OGnQAiOYDhjo2FJBCkcIgolLT0TCwE7Fw8-MISUMJiAN72UBlQNAjIwKrBuRjY+MQkBaEGIg6ZUEjoeDTAFGwo6BRSdXjyVKop2SF5sDkoRbiEQcPAYTQiAL5maTU1wAAWcjTa-bmJnd2bk9WZs-bHjvWNUNGJeBC8UB5ePn4BUouZAPTvUCRrdDQrvngBFqFAgnmgOCgoEg9AoFDaUBkCJsakIUPA0AARsgcGxslCVhAQGpQVAeMAoOgwMA5PUcPB0h8vgBJOhyClgdCuOSYxBQ9CItoBAnQUEXfRUNiYFjAOjAAXYynU2l4ekAfkZGS2KFUsgUSlU6i0NlUeCl2IoWmhEFUjQocjwVDM4lSUHeACp7gKaFgIKsHVQoO6vsd5vZ7NF9gMpAByOD6JArGNaACMWhj1pjJlsbq+P3WWQBbCBUF4bU4EY22uAsfj-iT2dzUDIaP9fyLJfpvBwIDoZYonCAA)

Comment: What's the use case for this? Presumably `thisIsAFunction` is going to call the callback with whatever arguments it's going to use to call the callback, regardless of how the callback's parameters are declared...? (Or are you going to sniff `.length` on the callback? If so, beware that `length` is fairly ...soft... now we have optional parameters and rest parameters.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the example was shortened, but it's important that the implementation of the callback knows that the arguments can be optional and need to be handled correctly

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added an extended example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, just typing the rest arguments as `undefined[]` seems to do the trick:

```
function thisIsAfunction<TArgs extends undefined[] = []>(callback: (firstParam: string, ...args: TArgs) => void) { 
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^
    /* Do something */ 
}

// This is okay ✅
thisIsAfunction((type: string, name?: string, id?: number) => {});

// This should cause a type error ❌
// (is it possible to force all args to be optional?)
thisIsAfunction((type: string, name: string, id: number) => {});
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFjAzgSXQQVJWBAHgBUcAnAc3UQFMAPKWsAExvBduBjFpYG0AuogC8iIQD4AFBACGAG3kAjWRADWALkRTu5dFAAKs8rIC2W-eR6UANIgB0j49S1kq6AJSiJiAG5wYFi8Ab0QAKERIxAB6ACpEABE4RHQ4U1pUa0RY6PCAXzCw6NySNBoMRDg1WQBPREBQcjDMrFx8aHgwKSkoGoAHWgsoKzBbRDAzWgB+QeHRwOmxkFMlWnIvER9gvI8AbkLixFKK9BQ4EHkWRDkQdFpEWWQ+u9XyOHJEQBlyItypCpgoRC9ODodAwJTyO5QZLAN4QO4KeT3dzIZIrSq9QjjeSTDxNMrYPDgdoILo9fozax2cbpCkjOyBLRgJYrNbeRBbXZAA)</sup>

---

For the extended version of the question, you could use a [mapped tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) (in this example named `Optionalized`):

```
type Optionalized<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | undefined };

type SelectCommand<TArgs extends unknown[]> = (filter: any, ...args: Optionalized<TArgs>) => void;

class DataSource<TSelectArgs extends unknown[] = []> {
    select: SelectCommand<TSelectArgs>;
    constructor(config: {select: SelectCommand<TSelectArgs>}) {
        this.select = config.select;
    }
}

const ds = new DataSource({
    select: (filter: any, id?: number, type?: string) => { /* Do something */ }
})

ds.select('Search', 1, 'type'); // This should work
ds.select('Search'); // And this should always work
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwQLwgEwB4AVAPigF4oBvKAbQGkoEUoBrCEJAMyiIF0AXLwZ8oAHygBXFHghdm+KAF8A3ACg1oSFADKEDBADGwAMJIAtubQziAQQBOAcwDOUCAA9gEGa+msUSADuKLR8ZJQAFPIYXvZC1iAANFAAdGloTs5CcIiomDj4dpkkAJQUZABuSAh46mqGGGjOrgAiaMBoOkiS9oYQxHoGxg4ubp7eeL4o-kEhopShZFRqUKtQzvpGwEKDW2aW1oREu8PF6mtQhqjOwPaSxkj2EVco8o5CVBtD27qbxvtWGzHP7AEbOEhKMrLC4XYAACwQzhSXy2FEuqDeyJB5zWSjUePq12AUEmaJQEECUDaHS6PT6EWhaxRxiEUQQMQgcSgCWSNQA-EIUJJzAAjTnJLQQAXrW7MRxlchLKAAegAVFSkOsLBB4XKoKrlcp8SUNJMsd8IgByPQZQxwy3JACMyUtkstJRUKsNRARrmccO6GDwUECj1YajNzOAVptvXtHq9UFsMigur9AckQe5GECaBArlD9nDaiAA)</sup>

As @SanBen points out in the comments, the `Optionalized` type in the example above can just as well replaced with TypeScript's [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility type.

Comment: Your solution works for the simple version, but it also makes it impossible to call the function if you use the type somewhere else. See my extended example in the question for more information.

Comment: @SanBen Updated my answer to address your extended example. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Actually I just realized you can use the [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) Type. It accomplishes the same as ```Optionalized```. This way the arguments can be omitted entirely.

Comment: @SanBen Ah, true. Hadn't thought of using that on a tuple.